# How do I put footnotes without putting any reference numerical mark on it?

Tags: footnotes

```
\footnotetext{TOV: Tolman, Oppenheimer, Volkoff (1939)}
\footnotetext{Richard C. Tolman: Phys. Rev 55 (1939), 364-373. Static Solutions of Einstein's Firld Equations for mass of Fluid.}
\footnotetext{ J.R Oppenheimer \& G. M Volkoff, phys Rev 55 (1939), 374-381. On Massive Stellar Core}
```

These footnote texts come up with superscripts and subscript numerical values. How do I get them cleaned?

Comment: Please always provide a complete example! What do you mean by subscript?

Comment: `\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{put text here}` and maybe you will need a `\stepcounter{footnote}` in front of the next one. Haven't tested that.

Comment: Some comments! 1st: What LaRiFaRi stated about the MWE, 2nd. `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}` in order to get non-numerical symbols. 3rd: Your footnotes are cites to bibliographic entries, try a bibliographic style with footnotes instead

Comment: Probably, the easiest way is to try if the `footnotetext`-environment from the `footnote`-package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote).